# How to use Multer middleware to upload array of images

Tags: node.js, react-native, upload, multer

Im trying to use Multer to upload an array of images. At the client side i have a FormData called pictures.

pictures array, from react-native-image-picker:

```
const [pictures, setPictures] = useState([]);
const imagePickerCallBack = data => {
    const picturesData = [...pictures];
    const index = picturesData.length;
    const image = {
      image: data.uri,
      fileName: data.fileName,
      type: data.type,
      index: index,
    };

    picturesData.push(image);

    setPictures(picturesData);
    setLoad(false);
  };
```

Step 1 - Create formData with all images:

```
const data = new FormData();

pictures.forEach(pic => {
        data.append('pictures', {
          fileName: pic.fileName,
          uri: pic.image,
          type: pic.type,
        });
      });
const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'x-access-token': token,
  };

const diaryUpdatePost = await post(`diary/uploadPictures/${diary}`, body, {
    headers,
  });
```

Step 2 - Get the request at server side. Im setting up multer and routers:

```
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/');
  },
  filename(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}`);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage, limits: { fieldSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024 } });

// Multer with the same FormData (client)
router.post('/uploadPictures/:name', upload.array('pictures'), diaryController.uploadDiaryPictures);
```

And finally my diaryController, where i need to get all files:

```
exports.uploadDiaryPictures = async (req, res) => {
  // Logging []. I cant access files from here
  console.log(`files ${req.files}...`);
};
```

I already tried to use express-fileupload, but req.files return undefined. Some ideia to help? Thx.

Comment: shouldn't you be sending `data` instead of `body` in Axios post request?

Comment: I'm just contextualizing the execution, but the post function is in another class, so it uses the body, which is a parameter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to give a count of files you expect to upload:

```
upload.array('pictures', <number_of_pictures>)
```

Or if it is allowed to be any number:

```
upload.any('pictures')
```

You should also add the file itself to your form data

```
data.append('pictures', {
    name: pic.fileName,
    file: pic.image,
    type: pic.type,
});
```

Comment: Hey bro, first of all, thx for helping. One question, i need to set file property with file uri?

Comment: @Flávio Costa, the `file` should be just the `file`.  If you iterate over files array then `file: pic`

Comment: Ok, i set multer middleware with upload.any('pictures'), and added file property, with pic value. But im still getting req.files.length = 0.

Comment: It could be because im not using the Multer config from App.js file?

Comment: No config of multer is required for frontend request

Comment: I realized that the request takes longer to reach the server when the formData uri parameter is filled. When I remove this parameter, the request happens very fast, as if there was no upload

Comment: can you add the code for how you created the pictures array?

Comment: I am out of options now. Your setup seems fine. As a final attempt can you try `file: pic.image`, `name: pic.fileName` setting

Comment: It didn't work; / I'll keep trying, when I get it resolved I comment here

Comment: I got it! You are right, changed fileName -> name and worked. Thx my friend.

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers here helped. The solution for me was to iteratively append **EACH** file object from the files array to the same field name given in Multer, instead of appending the files array *itself* to the field name given in Multer.

---

So from this:

```js
export const addFiles= createAsyncThunk(
  "addFiles",
  async (payload: any, thunkApi) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    // Here was the problem -- I was appending the array itself
    // to the "files" field
    formData.append("files", payload.files);
    formData.append("data", JSON.stringify(payload?.data || {}));

    const response = await axios.post('/user/products/files', formData);
    
    if(response){
      return response;
    }
    return thunkApi.rejectWithValue("");
  }
);
```

I did this:

```js
export const addFiles= createAsyncThunk(
  "addFiles",
  async (payload: any, thunkApi) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    // The following loop was the solution
    for (const file of payload.files) {
      formData.append("files", file);
    }
    formData.append("data", JSON.stringify(payload?.data || {}));

    const response = await axios.post('/user/products/files', formData);
    
    if(response){
      return response;
    }
    return thunkApi.rejectWithValue("");
  }
);
```

This was my Multer configuration:
`multer({ dest: "/uploads" }).array("files")`

The files posted to my endpoint were then available to me at:
`req.files`

PS: Although the accepted answer kind of did that, he did not mention that you cannot append the entire array at once, which was the main problem for me.