# Why multer is not uploading my image in the public folder?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer

I am creating one feature to upload images using multer . But i am not able to do so . A link is being created in the prescription but the image is not being saved in the public/images folder .

This is the jsx code.

```
<p>Upload Prescription</p>
      {selectedImage && (
        <div>
        <img alt="not found" width={"250px"} src={URL.createObjectURL(selectedImage)} />
        <br/>
        </div>
      )}
      <br />
     
      <br /> 
      <input
        type="file"
        name="image"
        onChange={(event) => {
          console.log('hi');
          console.log(event.target.files[0]);
          setSelectedImage(event.target.files[0]);
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={(e)=>{setSelectedImage(null)}}>
        Remove 
      </button>
    </div>
        </div>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>
            Add Record
        </button>
```

This is the handleClick function

```
const handleClick = async (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(URL.createObjectURL(selectedImage));
    const recordData =
    {
      diseasename,weight,height,medicines,desc,checkdate,patientId, prescription:URL.createObjectURL(selectedImage)
    }
    try{
      const res = await axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/api/record/createrecord",
         data: recordData,
         withCredentials: false
        });
      console.log(res.data);
    }
    catch(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

In controllers, I am setting prescription as req.file

```
import historyCard from "../models/historyCard.js";

export const medicalHistory = async(req,res,next) =>{
    console.log(req.file);
    try{
        // console.log(req.body);
        const newRecord = new historyCard({
            "diseasename":req.body.diseasename,
            "checkdate":req.body.checkdate,
            "weight":req.body.weight,
            "height":req.body.height,
            "desc":req.body.desc,
            "prescription":req.prescription
        })

        console.log(newRecord);
        await newRecord.save();
        res.status(200).send(newRecord);

    }catch(err){
        next(err);
    }
}
```

This is how i have imported multer

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, "./public/images");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(
        null,
        Date.now()+file.originalname
      );
    },
  });

const upload=multer({
    storage:storage,
    limits:{
        fieldSize:1024*1024*3
    }
})

const router = express.Router();
router.post('/addrecord',upload.single('image'),medicalHistory);
```

In database I am storing prescription as

```
prescription:{
        type:String,
        default: ""
    }
```

But the thing that is happening is , it is not being in my public folder.

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67523734/how-to-use-multer-middleware-to-upload-array-of-images/67524016#67524016?

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera I tried reading but i am not able to figure out whats wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

well, you're not sending the file.
You need to use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to send the file, and by using its [`.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) method, not an object, with `URL.createObject`

You can append the file separately, as well as `recordData` object by stringifying it, and then parse it on the server.

Since the file is stored in a public folder, you can store path to the file as a value of `prescription` property.
You can then add that property to the parsed `recordData` object on the server once the file is uploaded (and because only there can you know the file path, because of the custom filename), and then save the whole object:

try this:

on the client upload:

```
const handleClick = async (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(selectedImage.name);
    
    // add data, without prescription
    const recordData =
    {
      diseasename,weight,height,medicines,desc,checkdate,patientId
    }

    // use FormData
    const formData = new FormData();

    // append JSON data
    formData.append('recordData', JSON.stringify(recordData));

    // append file. the name should match the one on multer: upload.single('image'),
    formData.append('image', selectedImage);

    try{
      const res = await axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/api/record/createrecord",
         data: formData, // send formdata
         withCredentials: false
        });
      console.log(res.data);
    }
    catch(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

and on the controller parse `recordData`, and add file path as `prescription`'s property value:

```
  const recordData = JSON.parse(req.body.recordData);

  // save only path to the file, since it's in the public folder
  recordData.prescription = req.file.path;

  console.log('recordData', recordData);

  // save..
  const newRecord = new historyCard(recordData);
```

Comment: hey , it again dosent seem to work , again prescription is being saved as an empty string and also any console.log int the controller doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @AnshuJoshi then it's the component. are you setting the file, where's `setSelectedImage` part, there should be something like `const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);`, what does `console.log(selectedImage.name);` say